# how to add header and body tag to both header.asp and default.asp?

Tags: asp-classic

i tried to do this and i got an error.

this is the header:

```
<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--#include file="functions.asp"-->
</head>
<body>
<div>etc...
```

this is default.asp:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jh</title>
<link href="JHstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<!--#include file="/header.asp"-->
<!--#include file="header-jh.asp"-->
<table... etc
```

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: 500 (Internal Server) Error

Comment: Are you creating an ASP or ASP.NET application?

Comment: i don't know, it's just a simple website

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not used to classic ASP (this is different to the newer ASP.NET) it looks like you are creating a document structure error - the combined document would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jh</title>
<link href="JHstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--#include file="functions.asp"-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- div content etc. -->
<!--#include file="header-jh.asp"-->
<!-- Table and other content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the head and document elements appear twice, which is invalid - in any document the head and body elements should appear exactly once, with the head as the first child of the html element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/head and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/body

There is a new *header* element in HTML5 which is meant to represent the page header content within the body, as a new semantic element, but the head element should never appear as a child of body, or body as a child of head.

In PHP, the closest construct I have used to classic ASP, I would normally create a header.php file that would include the doctype, opening HTML tag, and entire head element - using variables to pass in the page title and any custom scripts/stylesheets. I don't know if this approach would work in classic ASP but conceptually there is no reason it shouldn't, you'll just need someone with more experience of classic ASP to advise you.

As it stands you'll either need to remove everything but the stylesheet(s) and functions.asp include reference from your header.asp file, and move the include up inside the head on the default.asp file, or start the head element in default.asp (to allow for the title) and finish it in header.asp (removing the closing head and opening body tags from default.asp).

With reference to the HTTP 500 error, this is a server error, and I would expect it to be a result of the server failing to locate one or more of your included files. Make sure that there are files functions.asp, header.asp and header-jh.asp in the same directory as default.asp - I'd also remove the leading / from header.asp - in other languages references to files are made relative to the directory containing the file, for example ../header.asp if the header.asp file is contained in the parent directory of default.asp, and not using HTML relative paths to the root of the website domain.

I hope this helps.